# Persistent Container returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am setting up core data in my iOS app. Iv'e followed the setup instructions step by step, but it keeps triggering the fatal error in the guard statement located in the root view controller, which is set to trigger fatalerror("error message") if the container var is nil. This is currently the only error that is causing the app to crash when loaded.

App Delegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Password_Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                
                fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
            }
            print("Persistent Var: Var did Finish Loading")

        }
        return container
    }()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        print("AppDelegate: Application didFinishLaunching")

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if let rootVC = window?.rootViewController as? PassWordTableVC{
            rootVC.container = persistentContainer
            
            print("AppDelegate container: \(rootVC.container!)")
        }
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


   
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

View controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PassWordTableVC: UITableViewController{
    
   var passwords = [[UsrPassword]]()
    
   var container: NSPersistentContainer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("Container in PassWordTableVC: \(container != nil ? "Not Nil" : "Nil")")

       guard container != nil else{
          fatalError("This view needs persistent container")
       }
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

         
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return passwords.count
    }
       
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return passwords[section].count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // Ask for a cell of the appropriate type.
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "passwordCell", for: indexPath) as! PasswordTableViewCell
            
        let thePassword = passwords[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
       // Configure the cell’s contents with the row and section number.
       // The Basic cell style guarantees a label view is present in textLabel.
        cell.passwordCellLabel!.text = thePassword.name
        print("Section \(indexPath.section)")
        
       return cell
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func unwindToSourceViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("Number of Passwords \(passwords.count)")
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let nextVc = segue.destination as? NewPassWordVC {
            nextVc.container = container
        }
    }
     
    
    
    



}
```

Comment: Is the `AppDelegate container` line printed? Another way is to initialize `container` in  `PassWordTableVC` lazily or – preferred – put the Core Data stack into a singleton class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply?  I will try putting CoreData into a singleton class.